# Почему на сайте визуально цвета разные?

Tags: html, css

Два разных локальный сайта, обозначение цветов одинаковое, но визуально они разные, на одном светлее на другом темнее.

В чем может быть причина?

Все перепроверено, ничего никто ни где не переопределяет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изза разного размера шрифта на больший шрифт приходится больше пикселей с цветом, поэтому визуально он кажется насыщеней.

Comment: Может слева есть прозрачность?

Comment: вы вкладку computed покажите, а не просто вкладку styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по тени от окна на скриншоте, снимок сделан в Chrome под MacOS — с обоими окнами в кадре. Это имеет значение, т.к. рендеринг шрифтов  сильно зависит от настроек операционной системы.

[image: увеличенный скриншот]

В вашем примере точно применён один и тот же цвет #008000, но используются разные методы сглаживания. Слева — **субпиксельный** метод [ClearType](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType), а справа обычный антиалиазинг.

Устанавливать с помощью CSS разные методы сглаживания (не считая его полного отключения) можно как раз только для MacOS при помощи правил `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` (похоже на то, что слева) и `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` (похоже на то, что справа).

Если причина разного отображения окажется не в этом свойстве, то скорее всего, она вообще вне области действия CSS, но как-то связана с настройками системы.